# flutter_local_notification Grouping notification not working

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm new to `flutter` and I'm tired of grouping notification from `Firebase Push Notification`. I am using `flutter_local_notification` plugin for showing notification in notification bar.

I'm getting different tabs for every notification. So i have used grouping feature of this plugin for grouping notifications.

But it seems not working still it is getting as multiple notifications in notification bar. Any help would be appreciated. I tried this in api level above 24 as their document says.

Sample code i tried is as below.

```
String groupKey = 'com.android.example.WORK_EMAIL';

String groupChannelId = 'grouped channel id';

String groupChannelName = 'grouped channel name';

String groupChannelDescription = 'grouped channel description';

AndroidNotificationDetails firstNotificationAndroidSpecifics =
    new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        groupChannelId, groupChannelName, groupChannelDescription,
        importance: Importance.Max,
        priority: Priority.High,
        groupKey: groupKey);

NotificationDetails firstNotificationPlatformSpecifics =
    new NotificationDetails(firstNotificationAndroidSpecifics, null);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(1, 'Alex Faarborg',
    'You will not believe...', firstNotificationPlatformSpecifics);

AndroidNotificationDetails secondNotificationAndroidSpecifics =
    new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        groupChannelId, groupChannelName, groupChannelDescription,
        importance: Importance.Max,
        priority: Priority.High,
        groupKey: groupKey);

NotificationDetails secondNotificationPlatformSpecifics =
    new NotificationDetails(secondNotificationAndroidSpecifics, null);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    2,
    'Jeff Chang',
    'Please join us to celebrate the...',
    secondNotificationPlatformSpecifics);
```

Comment: did you found any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

After much tinkering, the solution below works for me. You only need to `setAsGroupSummary: true` only to the first notification. My implementaion of `AndroidNotificationDetails` would be as below (im using `BigTextStyleInformation` btw):

```
AndroidNotificationDetails _androidDetails(_NotificationType type, bool isGroupContainer) =>
      AndroidNotificationDetails(
          _NotificationPreference.GROUP_CHANNEL_ID,
          _NotificationPreference.GROUP_CHANNEL_NAME,
          _NotificationPreference.GROUP_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION,
          groupKey: _NotificationPreference.GROUP_CHANNEL,
          icon: _NotificationPreference.APP_ICON,
          priority: Priority.high,
          importance: Importance.max,
          setAsGroupSummary: isGroupContainer,
          styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(type.getDetails.body,
              contentTitle: type.getDetails.title));

NotificationDetails _flutterNotificationDetails(_NotificationType type, bool isGroupContainer) =>
      NotificationDetails(android: _androidDetails(type, isGroupContainer), iOS: _iosDetails);
```

so to show multiple notification in a single group:

```
  @override
  Future<void> showNotification() async {
    await plugin.show(0, '', '',
        _flutterNotificationDetails(_NotificationType.Container,true), payload: '1');
    await plugin.show(_NotificationType.Type1.getDetails.id, _NotificationType.Type1.getDetails.title, _NotificationType.Type1.getDetails.body,
        _flutterNotificationDetails(_NotificationType.Type1,false));
    await plugin.show(_NotificationType.Type2.getDetails.id, _NotificationType.Type2.getDetails.title, _NotificationType.Type2.getDetails.body,
        _flutterNotificationDetails(_NotificationType.Type2,false));
  }
```

this will show a group notification with 2 children in it.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
setAsGroupSummary: true
```

in your AndroidNotificationDetails